# What would our Sun look like from other solar systems?

Tags: star, the-sun, solar-system

I came across an [article](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/what-the-sun-looks-like-from-other-planets_n_577ec142e4b0344d514e9182) that shows how the Sun looks from other planets of our solar system.

Now I am wondering, how does our Sun look from an exoplanet? I am guessing it must be looking like a 'star', but I wanted some reference to support that.

Comment: For what it's worth: The answer on [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17419/most-distant-photo-of-the-sun) shows the most distant photo ever taken of the Sun.  And it's still not nearly far enough to look like what other stars look like to us.

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/a

Comment: @darrel-hoffman Thanks for information and linking https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17419/m

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sun is a yellow dwarf star, so looking at any yellow dwarf star in the night sky will give a good example. Alpha Centauri A is also a yellow dwarf, albeit a little bigger than the sun, so our view of it should be similar to the view of our sun from Alpha Centauri.

From [NASA's page on it](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/chandra/images/alpha-centauri-a-triple-star-system-about-4-light-years-from-earth.html), here is a lovely image:

[image]

Comment: And for everyone wondering, how bright would it be, and where in the night sky would I find the Sun, [this website](https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-blogs/explore-night-bob-king/see-the-sun-from-other-stars/) has answers for several more or less nearby star systems. From Alpha Centauri, the Sun would be a pretty conspicuous star in the Cassiopeia constellation.

Comment: @sebastian-koppehel thanks for 
https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-blogs/explore-night-bob-king/see-the-sun-from-other-stars/